# Need help overriding a WPF button style background color.

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the below code set for a custom button. But I want to change the background for a single button.

```
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FF2F2FEA" Stroke="Black">
                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                </Rectangle>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="2.833,0,2.5,1.162" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="69.667"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

The code below is meant to override the background color but doesn't. What am I missing? Thanks

```
<Style x:Key="SpecialButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGreen" />
   <Setter Property="Height" Value="19.96" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2F2FEA" />` to the `myButtonStyle`. And change the `Fill` on the `Rectangle` to `Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"`

```
<Style x:Key="myButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2F2FEA" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="Black">
                        <Rectangle.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
                        </Rectangle.Effect>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                    Margin="2.833,0,2.5,1.162" 
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="69.667"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

After this, the two `Button`s should show up properly.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="BASE" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}"></Button>

    <Button Content="DERIVED" Style="{StaticResource SpecialButton}"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Result:

[image: result]

Explanation: if you change the `Template` of a `Control` you have to "wire-up" its properties (like `Background`, `Foreground`, `HorizontalContentAlignment` etc) to properties of elements in the `ControlTemplate`. After all you want to give the ability to end users of the control to modify the color, alignment etc, and not just have a `Control` with a static visual tree.

Comment: You beat me to it :)), Yes when you override the ControlTemplate of the button the Button's Background was of no use, unless you use a template binding to it (y)

Comment: Well that did the trick. This XAML stuff sure has a tuff learning curve. Thanks for the Explanation too!